# HeatMap in Open Layers with function instead of url

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

Today I use open layers to load heat points on a map.
I use the following code:

It uses a physical file to load these hot spots, where every time I need to create the file and then delete it. I would like to start using a function so I don't have to do this.

```
 // HeatMap
    const heatMapPontosCalor = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: './data/PontosCalor.geojson',
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        }),
        radius: 20,
        blur: 12,
        gradient: ['#0000FF', '#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FFA500', '#FF0000'],
        title: 'PontosCalor',
        visible: false,
    })
```

where in: './data/PontosCalor.geojson', I have

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "weight": 0.8
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -52.420033886945845,
          -26.868413221745136
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

here using the file loads correctly

[image]

here I tried to create the function

```
function loadGeoJSONData() {

  const geoJSONData = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "weight": 0.8
        },
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [-52.420033886945845, -26.868413221745136],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  return geoJSONData;
}


const heatMapPontosCalor = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(loadGeoJSONData()),
  }),
  radius: 20,
  blur: 12,
  gradient: ['#0000FF', '#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FFA500', '#FF0000'],
  title: 'PontosCalor',
  visible: false,
});
```

but now the heat point loads in a random place on the map

[image]

What am I doing wrong/not doing?

Comment: Try to add `format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()` to the Object

Comment: You must specify the `featureProjection` for `readFeatures` https://openlayers.org/en/main/apidoc/module-ol_format_GeoJSON-GeoJSON.html#readFeatures Features must be read into the view projection to be displayed correctly.